# define directive with parameter pack gives expecting an expression error

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

My C++ is very rusty from non use so this may be a very trivial issue. I am running a DLL project in C++ on Visual Studio 2019. I have a define directive with parameter pack such as the following:

```
#define FUNC(...)              \
    try                        \
    {                          \
        (__VA_ARGS__);         \
    }                          \
    catch (std::exception & e) \
    {                          \
        LOG("error: %s", e);   \
        return STATUSERROR;    \
    }                          \
    return STATUSOK;
```

This works when i call:

```
 FUNC( i = 0);
```

But when I try to call the following, it throws an error "expected an expression"

```
FUNC({
     if(some_statement){
         return something;
     }
     return something_else;
});
```

I am using \ as a line continuation escape character so the issue does not stem from that. I have compiled this with both C++ 14 and 17. What may I be missing here?

Comment: Your macro declaration is missing quite a few backslashes. Right now it defines `FUNC` as nothing and then drops a `try`/`catch` into what I assume is the global scope.

Comment: the backslashes are actually there but stackoverflow isnt rendering them, after many attempts I wasnt able to make them visible

Comment: I've fixed it, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro call expands to `({ /* stuff */ });`, which is not valid syntax. It may be that the code was originally compiled with GCC, which offers it as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

You should remove the parentheses and semicolon from the macro expansion, leaving `__VA_ARGS__` on its own to fill the enclosing scope.

Comment: Thanks you are right about it being compiled with GCC prior, I made the changes and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quentin is correct unsurprisingly. Changing the macro to

```
#define FUNC(...)              \
try                        \
{                          \
    __VA_ARGS__            \
}                          \
catch (std::exception & e) \
{                          \
    LOG("error: %s", e);   \
    return STATUSERROR;    \
}                          \
return STATUSOK;
```

And using it like so

```
FUNC(
 if(some_statement){
     return something;
 }
 return something_else;
);
```

Preprocessing with (gcc version = 10.2.0) `gcc -E file.cpp` and manually reformatting for legibility yields

```
 try { 
    if(some_statement){ 
       return something; 
 } 
 return something_else; 
} 
catch (std::exception & e) 
{ 
  LOG("error: %s", e); return STATUSERROR; 
}
return STATUSOK;
```

But I still hate macros.